# why one line python loop and traditional loop return different results?

Tags: python

I have array, where I for sure know, there are two objects, which meet conditions, that I want to loop

if I do

```
def filter_checks_by_lcode_and_admin(admin_uid, lcode, checks):

    result = []
    for check in checks:
      if check.lcode == lcode and check.admin == admin_uid:
         result.append(check)
    return result
```

returns correct array with 2 objects

but this code

```
def filter_checks_by_lcode_and_admin(admin_uid, lcode, checks):
    return [check for check in checks if check.admin == admin_uid and check.lcode == lcode]
```

return 0

what im I doing wrong ?

Comment: That second snippet definitely doesn't return an integer. Please give a [mre].

Comment: @jonrsharpe OP means to say that the second snippet returns a list with 0 elements.

Comment: Probably harmless, but why did you change the order of the two conditions?

Comment: @AlexeyK the only explanation is that the input is different, otherwise both versions are equivalent. We can't test this hypothesis, please post the sample input you're using for each snippet.

Comment: @ÓscarLópez Well, `admin` or `lcode` could also be a property/getter affecting the value of the other, so that the order matters.

Answer (score 1):

Until we have a sample input, we can only speculate. In *principle* both versions of your code should be equivalent, but just to be sure write the conditions in the same order in both:

```
def filter_checks_by_lcode_and_admin(admin_uid, lcode, checks):
    return [check for check in checks if check.lcode == lcode and check.admin == admin_uid]
```

If that changes the result, then it's because your code has some kind of side effect that makes the result be different between invocations depending on the *order* of execution. Certainly something to avoid, as you can see, it'll lead to hard to find bugs.

Also you can try executing your code with the same input, but trying the second snippet first and the first snippet later. If this works, then again it'll be a sign that *something* is changing the state of the inputs between executions, definitely a problem that should be fixed.

Comment: This is what I did while debugging  - same input, different loops. Leaded to different result, unfortunately

Comment: @AlexeyK Unclear what you're saying. This version here gives the same result as which one of your two versions?

Comment: @AlexeyK In case I wasn't clear: please post the sample input, provide a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)